# GTM - How would I go about creating an array of data from my dataLayer to use as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm currently setting up GTM/GA4 on my e-commerce site (using LightspeedPOS so no site builder like WordPress), and I only have a very basic understanding of JavaScript. I'm adding the parameters to all the events and tags I have set up, and Google documentation suggests setting up the item(s) in an array. [Google Documentation (add_payment_info event as example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6Jqa.png)

I want to pull certain values (item_id, item_name, quantity, etc.) from the **eventModel** object in the dataLayer and compile them into an array to send to GA4 as a parameter, that way I can track what customers are purchasing. No matter the event that I'm using (view_cart, add_to_cart, etc.) the eventModel is present. I'm aware of using the dot notation to pull from specific items in the array, but I want to write a custom JavaScript code variable to pull these values from all the items present in the *items* array, no matter if it's one item or twenty of them. This is what my dataLayer looks like for a begin_checkout event:

```
{
  event: "begin_checkout",
  gtm: {
    uniqueEventId: 18,
    allowlist: undefined,
    blocklist: undefined,
    whitelist: undefined,
    blacklist: undefined,
    priorityId: undefined,
    start: 1691511957097
  },
  url_passthrough: false,
  tagTypeBlacklist: undefined,
  ads_data_redaction: false,
  developer_id: {'': true},
  eventModel: {
    value: 291.99,
    currency: "USD",
    coupon: "",
    items: [
      {
        item_id: "MET1920",
        item_name: "Branch Cheese Server Set",
        coupon: "",
        item_brand: "",
        price: 26,
        quantity: 1,
        currency: "USD"
      },
      {
        item_id: "DF4322",
        item_name: "Stoneware Tray",
        coupon: "",
        item_brand: "",
        price: 24,
        quantity: 1,
        currency: "USD"
      },
      {
        item_id: "DF4638",
        item_name: "Wooden Chain Decor",
        coupon: "",
        item_brand: "",
        price: 28,
        quantity: 1,
        currency: "USD"
      },
      {
        item_id: "NTRP1033",
        item_name: "Mond Pods",
        coupon: "",
        item_brand: "",
        price: 9.99,
        quantity: 1,
        currency: "USD"
      },
      {
        item_id: "DF2497",
        item_name: "Glass Table Lamp",
        coupon: "",
        item_brand: "",
        price: 153,
        quantity: 1,
        currency: "USD"
      },
      {
        item_id: "DF5971",
        item_name: "Paper Mache Bowl",
        coupon: "",
        item_brand: "",
        price: 51,
        quantity: 1,
        item_variant: "Large",
        currency: "USD"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

To clarify all that info a bit, the eventModel object contains an items array, and I want to pull the values from item_id, item_name, etc. of each item present in the array and put them into their own array for GA4 to read. How would I go about doing this?

I used a custom template variable that turns items from an array into a string, but then I would have to create a variable for each string of data I want to extract (item_id, item_name, etc.) and add them as a parameter individually. I only want one parameter that contains all the information I'm trying to extract in order to simplify the process a bit and make it easier for GA4 to present the data.

I also tried writing my own function seen here:

```
function() {
    var items = {{Data Layer - Items}};
    if (items && Array.isArray(items)) {
        var itemDetails = items.map(function(item) {
            return {
                item_id: item.item_id || '',
                item_name: item.item_name || '',
                item_variant: item.item_variant || '',
                item_brand: item.item_brand || '',
                item_category: item.item_category || '',
                quantity: item.quantity || '',
                price: item.price || 0,
                currency: item.currency || '',
                coupon: item.coupon || ''
            };
        });
        
        return JSON.stringify(itemDetails);
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

And this is what the output looks like in GTM:[GTM JavaScript variable output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVNDa.png)

This doesn't seem to be correctly outputting efficiently as there's a lot of clutter compared to other variables, so I was wondering what my JavaScript code should look like in order to properly do the task.

Answer (score 0):

First, these values that you see in the DL are most likely a result of gtag() function usage. And gtag() populating DL is only a side-effect of the main action that it does: sending data to GA.

In short, this data you're trying to send to GA has most likely alraedy been sent to GA once by gtag.js. This is why we typically discourage people from using gtag.js and gtm in parallel: too much confusion about what's happening.

I didn't run your code, but from the JS var output it seems to be working fine given how you stringify it. Try remove the stringification and see if the "clutter" goes away.

Did chatGPT write this code for you?

Comment: Many of the tutorials I've watched when setting up GTM and GA4 warned me of the same thing: don't use gtag.js and GTM together. I've only been using GTM, and, yes, I got ChatGPT to write some of the base code. I did make some changes to it, but figured the JSON stringify was necessary as I know nothing about JSON code. I ended up going with a similar, but different, code without the stringify and my data displays without the "clutter"

Comment: Yep, good job on all fronts. ChatGPT wrote some ok code.

Comment: Does anyone have a step-by-step explanation for how to send an array of values through GTM to GA4? I'm confused by the stringinfication step (and who unstringifies it?). I was under the impression if I sent an event with a property that was a plan js array some configuration of gtm variables and possibly GA dimensions would capture it as an array, at present I'm getting nothing but the event and it's basic string properties.